# Is a vector more appropriate in my case -  C++

Tags: arrays, performance, vector

I have read on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that vectors are faster than arrays for reading and writing. I have an interesting problem with my program where the file I am reading in contains numerous fragments of different types and yet I have no idea how many fragments of each type there are until I read them. So for instance if fragment 1 can be identified by

```
struct frag_1
{
    int number1;
    int number2;
};
```

I have looped though the file one, counter how many times each fragment type appears, allocate arrays of memory with the type being the fragment struct, like the example struct, and then I fill them and manipulate them.

It looks as if vectors though are much faster for reading and writing, dynamic as I can add to them on the fly, and generally better practice.

Is this true? Thank you.

Comment: *"I have read on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that vectors are faster than arrays for reading and writing."* I highly doubt the veracity of that statement. At best, it's a micro-optimization.

Comment: At best, that's completely wrong. :-)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I saw a few benchmarks that said vectors were indeed faster.

Comment: @SatchmoBrown: It's impossible because vectors *use arrays* underneath...

Comment: @SatchmoBrown: vectors are typically implemented *using* an array, and can thus, logically, can only perform that fast or slower. However, the convenience a vector offers typically vastly outweighs the typically minor difference in read/write performance. I'd love to see the benchmark making such a claim that vectors were faster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for this pattern, a [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/) is usually the best choice. Using a `vector` for this purpose, unless you can at least roughly guess at the final size, will require a large number of allocate/copy/free cycles as the implementation uses vectors that are too small.

Comment: What is the advantage of a deque that isn't there in a vector. I like the fact a deque element can be accessed by index. Also, what kind of range are we talking here in guessing the size. I assume you're talking about the reserve function so there isn't a bunch of reallocation but let's say for this example, I chose 200 and the actual size was 450. What kind of performance hit can I expect?

Comment: You can do one of two things. You can pick the optimum structure from the beginning or you can not worry about it until and unless you have performance problems. You seem to be trying to split the difference between these two strategies in some weird way. Enlarging a vector will take an allocate/copy/deallocate pass. Enlarging a deque won't. How much the hit is will depend on the details of the implementation and the access pattern. If you pick a deque, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: How do you figure that enlarging a deque *won't* require an allocate/copy/deallocate, without relying on a particular implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two lists of objects here: The fragments themselves, and `number1` and `number2` as members of this particular type of fragment.

First, the fragments themselves. Given your description, use a `std::vector`, especially if you don't know in advance how many fragments you'll have. (Which you state.) It'll do the memory allocation for you, and greatly reduce the change of error, which greatly outweighs any  (really tiny) speed improvements doing it yourself would earn.

As for the members, consider:

```
struct frag_1
{
    int numbers[2];
};
```

(Also, consider better variable names, as that might lead you (or us) to a more definitive answer as to which is "better".)

Note that I've only considered vector vs. array for your use. If you later need to lookup some fragment by some member, then some type of mapping type might be more appropriate. If you're just loading and looping through all the fragments (and using them all), then a `std::vector` is typically fine for most cases.

---

**On `std:vector`s performance during resizes:** If you know the eventual size of the vector, you can inform the vector ahead of time. If you don't know the eventual size, then you don't know, and resizes and memory allocations can happen *regardless of container*. Most containers, even with reallocations happening, will give O(*n*) performance. The question you're asking, and what the other post appears to be implying, is that `resize` will be your bottleneck. So: **profile**. More than likely, the vector will get the job done, and do it quickly enough that you won't care about the resizes. If you're reading stuff from disk, the disk I/O alone will often so vastly outweigh the resize operations that optimizing them makes little sense.

Comment: Some had said the performance hit from not knowing an approximate size (I figure they are referring to the reserve function) will kill the performance. What say you?